# Getting background image to scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm running a background video when visitors enter the landing page.  As you scroll down the page the video stays in place but I would like to change this so the video scrolls out as well.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is my CSS:

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.video-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.video-container-bg {
    padding-top: 45vh;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And here is the HTML which uses it:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-container-bg">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
                <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="animation-element bounce-up">
                        <h1 class="page-title">{{page.page_title}}</h1>
                        <p class="strapeline">{{page.strapline}}</p>
                        <a class="butt" href="#about-us">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `position:relative` instead of fixed

```css
video#bgvid { 
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.video-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.video-container-bg {
    padding-top: 45vh;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-container-bg">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
                <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="animation-element bounce-up">
                        <h1 class="page-title">{{page.page_title}}</h1>
                        <p class="strapeline">{{page.strapline}}</p>
                        <a class="butt" href="#about-us">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-container-bg">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
                <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="animation-element bounce-up">
                        <h1 class="page-title">{{page.page_title}}</h1>
                        <p class="strapeline">{{page.strapline}}</p>
                        <a class="butt" href="#about-us">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-container-bg">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
                <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="animation-element bounce-up">
                        <h1 class="page-title">{{page.page_title}}</h1>
                        <p class="strapeline">{{page.strapline}}</p>
                        <a class="butt" href="#about-us">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is the next div no longer sits over the top of it, which it must do

Comment: can you explain in brief

Comment: The `div class="container"` section has text and links in it and it should sit over the video.  When I change position to relative it just shifts that section below the video.